# How to import/require existing Non-React-Native-Component JS to a React Native Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I have a pretty big javascript legacy code base of a WebApplication, which includes the presentation/data model/controller/connectivity. I'm trying to replace the presentation layer technology with ReactNative, while keep the existing data model/controller/connectivity parts. So the first question is, after I built the ReactNativeComponent where we have the UI layout defined, binding established, styles created... but I need to call some js functions from the legacy code.
How can I require/import an existing js file (not a ReactNativeComponent) to one ReactNativeComponent and use it?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem before too. Something I did, unable to find more elegant solutions, was to wrap my legacy code in a module.

Let's say this is `foo.js`

```
var Foo = (function() {
  var mod = {
    init: function() {
      // legacy code here...
    }
  }

  return mod;
})()

module.exports = Foo;
```

then in calling file:

```
import foo from './somewhere/foo';
foo.init();
```

I didn't love this approach, but it worked. Hopefully it can somewhat help.

Answer (score 1):

If they're purely js then you can import them normally. If they have anything to do with html/css/dom it will throw an error.